# Ending the program-Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make this program end straight away without asking the question " The program is still running,Do you want to kill it? " if the wrong password entered for the third time. Tried using 'quit()' but the program become not responding. Please help me.

```
import Tkinter



global root
global s
# this is the main/root window
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Stock Plus system")
root.geometry('800x600')
b2Var=Tkinter.StringVar()
s = 1


def win2():
    # this is the child window






    labelcementin = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Cement quantity in:')
    labelcementin.grid(row=1,column=1)
    labelhammerin = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Hammer quantity in;')
    labelhammerin.grid(row=2,column=1)
    labelspannerin = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Spanner quantity in:')
    labelspannerin.grid(row=3,column=1)
    labelbrickin = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Brick quantity in:')
    labelbrickin.grid(row=4,column=1)
    labelmirrorin = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Mirror quantity in:')
    labelmirrorin.grid(row=5,column=1)

    labelcementout = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Cement quantity out:')
    labelcementout.grid(row=1,column=3)
    labelhammerout = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Hammer quantity out:')
    labelhammerout.grid(row=2,column=3)
    labelspannerout = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Spanner quantity out:')
    labelspannerout.grid(row=3,column=3)
    labelbrickout = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Brick quantity out:')
    labelbrickout.grid(row=4,column=3)
    labelmirrorout = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Mirror quantity out:')
    labelmirrorout.grid(row=5,column=3)

    def calc_val():

        Total_StockIn=int(cementinVar.get())+int(hammerinVar.get())+int(spannerinVar.get())+int(brickinVar.get())+int(mirrorinVar.get())
        StockInLabel=Tkinter.Label(root,text='The total stock in is '+str(Total_StockIn))
        StockInLabel.grid(row=8,column=2)

        Total_Expenses= (int(cementinVar.get())*16)+(int(hammerinVar.get())*10)+(int(spannerinVar.get())*8)+(int(brickinVar.get())*2)+(int(mirrorinVar.get())*22)
        ExpensesLabel=Tkinter.Label(root,text='The total expenses is RM ' + str(Total_Expenses))
        ExpensesLabel.grid(row=9,column=2)

        Total_Income= (int(cementoutVar.get())*18)+(int(hammeroutVar.get())*12)+(int(spanneroutVar.get())*10)+(int(brickoutVar.get())*4)+(int(mirroroutVar.get())*25)
        IncomeLabel = Tkinter.Label(root,text = 'The Total income is RM ' +str(Total_Income))
        IncomeLabel.grid(row=8, column= 4)

        Remaining_Stock =Total_StockIn-(int(cementoutVar.get())+int(hammeroutVar.get())+int(spanneroutVar.get())+int(brickoutVar.get())+int(mirroroutVar.get()))
        RemainingLabel = Tkinter.Label(root,text = 'The remaining stock is ' + str(Remaining_Stock))
        RemainingLabel.grid(row=9, column = 4)

        Total_Profit = (Total_Income) - (Total_Expenses)
        ProfitLabel = Tkinter.Label(root,text = 'The total profit is RM ' + str(Total_Profit))
        ProfitLabel.grid(row=10, column = 3)

        quit()






    boxcementin = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=cementinVar)
    boxcementin.grid(row=1, column=2)
    boxhammerin = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=hammerinVar)
    boxhammerin.grid(row=2, column=2)
    boxspannerin = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=spannerinVar)
    boxspannerin.grid(row=3, column=2)
    boxbrickin = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=brickinVar)
    boxbrickin.grid(row=4, column=2)
    boxmirrorin = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=mirrorinVar)
    boxmirrorin.grid(row=5, column=2)

    boxcementout = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=cementoutVar)
    boxcementout.grid(row=1, column=4)
    boxhammerout = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=hammeroutVar)
    boxhammerout.grid(row=2, column=4)
    boxspannerout = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=spanneroutVar)
    boxspannerout.grid(row=3, column=4)
    boxbrickout = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=brickoutVar)
    boxbrickout.grid(row=4, column=4)
    boxmirrorout = Tkinter.Entry(root,width=12,textvariable=mirroroutVar)
    boxmirrorout.grid(row=5, column=4)





    button = Tkinter.Button(root,text='Calculate',command=calc_val)
    button.grid(row=7,column=3)







def textboxvalue():
#For password entry
    global s

    if (s!=3 ):
       Password=b2Var.get()
       Username=b1Var.get()
       if Password ==('stock123'):
           label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Welcome to stock plus system, press login again to start using')
           label4.grid(row=0,column=3)
           Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=win2)
           Button_1.grid(row=7,column=3)



       else:
           s =s+1
           label3=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Try again')
           label3.grid(row=3,column=1)

    else:
        label5=Tkinter.Label(root,text='bye')
        label5.grid(row=4,column=4)
        label6=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Thank You for using Stock Plus System ')
        label6.grid(row=5,column=4)







#Widgets in main window
Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=textboxvalue)
Button_1.grid(row=7, column=3)
b1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
b2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

box1Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Username:')
box1Label.grid(row=1,column=3)
box2Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Password:')
box2Label.grid(row=2,column=3)
box1Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b1Var,width=12)
box1Text.grid(row=1, column=4)
box2Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b2Var,width=12,show='*')
box2Text.grid(row=2, column=4)

cementinVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
hammerinVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
spannerinVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
brickinVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
mirrorinVar = Tkinter.IntVar()

cementoutVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
hammeroutVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
spanneroutVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
brickoutVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
mirroroutVar = Tkinter.IntVar()




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried using `quit()`, instead of just telling us you tried it? Also, can you give us a [complete minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a fragment?

Comment: The answer _may_ just be that you need to add a `something.destroy()`, but I can't tell that from what you've shown us (or guess what that `something` needs to be; maybe `root`, but I can't be sure).

Comment: OK, first, you almost never want to use `quit()` from application-type code. For command-line programs, use `sys.exit()`. For Tkinter GUIs, call the `quit` _method_ on the appropriate window, usually `root.quit()`. That probably won't solve your whole problem, but it may solve the "not responding" one.

Comment: Also, please read the link to the MCVE help in my first comment. Don't post your whole program, post a stripped-down program without all the irrelevant stuff, just enough to demonstrate what you're asking for help with.

Comment: @abarnert Where do you suggest i put the root.quit(), same place as i put the quit()

Comment: Meanwhile, the place where you added `quit()` isn't the place you're trying to quit from. Putting a `quit()` inside `calc_val`, which only happens after the user has logged in and calculated a value, isn't going to help you quit the app when they fail to login.

Comment: tried the  "root.quit()"  application still became not responding, any other methods you think would work?

Comment: Did you try the `root.destroy()` in my answer?

Comment: Meanwhile: what platform and platform version (including 32-/64-bit if WIndows), what Python version (including 32-/64-bit if Windows), what Tcl/Tk version (if on Mac or Linux and you installed/upgraded it yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two, or maybe three, problems with your use of `quit`.

First, you put it in the wrong place. You want to quit if the user fails to login three times. But your `quit()` call comes at the end of `calcval`, which only gets called after the user has successfully logged in and calculated a value, so of course it's not going to help.

Second, you called the wrong thing. The `quit` *function* is a special thing used for quitting the interactive interpreter. You usually shouldn't use it in applications at all (use `sys.exit()` for command-line programs), and especially not in GUI apps. The `quit` *method* is called on the same Tkinter window you called `mainloop()` on, and tells it to quit the main loop.

So, what you want to do is add this line inside the `else` block that has the `Thank You for using Stock Plus System` text:

```
root.quit()
```

---

That may not work, depending on your platform, and how you're running your program—or, if you're running from IDLE, it may cause IDLE to quit as well. Tkinter is finicky. If you have the first problem, add this line before the `quit`; if you have the second problem, use it *instead of* the `quit`.

```
root.destroy()
```

If you want to understand, see [this thread](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/66698/exit-a-tkinter-gui-program). Briefly: `destroy` destroys any widget and all of its children. And when you call it on a root widget that owns the mainloop, it also ends the loop. `quit` sends a message to the mainloop that tells it to destroy all widgets it knows about and then kill the Tcl interpreter. Normally, it should always be safe to just `quit`, but there are some cases where it can miss a widget and freeze up—and when you're running under IDLE, you may be sharing the same Tcl interpreter as IDLE itself, so `quit` may kill or hang it as well.

Comment: The last  one `root.destroy()`  and adding  `quit()`     below it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to use

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

or directly

```
raise SystemExit(0)
```

Comment: The program became not responding

Comment: That's almost certainly going to have the same effect as his existing code. It's better to use `sys.exit()` than `quit()`, but you shouldn't use either in a Tkinter app without shutting down the Tkinter loop first.